# Criar tabela excel baseada em filtro

Tags: microsoft-excel

Olá,

Eu tenho uma tabela no Excel de 3 colunas:

```
Pessoa | ID | País
João   | 1  | Flórida
Maria  | 2  | Flórida
Ana    | 3  | Miami
Ana    | 4  | Califórnia
Pedro  | 5  | Califórnia
João   | 6  | Flórida
```

etc...

Gostaria de construir uma tabela que contivesse as pessoas somente da 'Flórida' para que eu pudesse referenciar em uma outra planilha.

Tentei usar a Segmentação de Dados, porém ela funciona apenas como um filtro, e eu não consigo fazer as referências dinâmicas de tabela (ele não fica [@Pessoa], por exemplo, mas sim referenciado na célula). Gostaria, então, de construir uma subtabela que contivesse apenas as pessoas da Flórida, de forma que, quando eu atualizar os dados dessa tabela, essa subtabela também se atualize (mas seja uma tabela, não um 'filtro').

Alguém tem alguma sugestão? Tentei uma Query, porém a subtabela dá erro quando atualizo minha tabela original.

Obrigada!

Comment: "Tentei uma Query", você está se referindo aquela opção do "Microsoft Query" que fica no menu Dados? Pois fiz um teste aqui e funcionou, edite a pergunta e coloque qual erro aparece.

Answer (score 1):

Copiar e Colar não te resolve o problema? Se sim, use o comando para selecionar apenas células visíveis:

Selecione a sua tabela inteira ou as colunas que deseja consolidar sua nova lista. Filtre por 'Flórida' e siga a instrução abaixo:

```
Aba Início > Localizar e Selecionar > Ir para... > Especial... > Apenas célilas visíveis
```

Em seguida, selecione OK, aperte Crtl+C e cole na área desejada.

[image: passo a passo]

Answer (score 0):

Utilizar uma Tabela Dinâmica não lhe ajudaria? Assim vc pode colocar fórmulas ao lado da Tabela Dinâmica e não ter o problema de referência ou linhas ocultas ao filtrar. Além disso, vc pode inserir Slicers para fazer os filtros.

[image: Tabela Dinâmica]

Caso precise de orientaão de como montar a tabela dinâmica dessa form, me avise!